# ipad default-landscape not displaying

Tags: ipad, screen-orientation

I have added both images. Default-Portrait.png and Default-Landscape.png. But whenever I start my app, only the portrait default image is displayed irrespective of the orientation.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding the following to the Info.plist file (from Xcode):

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Genius. This has been killing me for days!

Answer (score -7):

Did you add code to swap out the images based on orientation?  I am guessing the app just is not going to know what picture you want unless you tell it.

UIInterfaceOrientation param