# Programmatically change view orientation without rotating ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, rotation, orientation

I would like to rotate a ViewController based on some condition. The problem with shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is that the view always start with portrait/landscape orientation (as set in Interface Builder) and the user has to rotate the ipad to use the correct mode.... How can I change this behavior?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a transform to the view.

`view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);`

You can use UIView animations to animate the change.

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Thank you. Another thing: will this usse autosizing rules defined in Interf Builder?

Comment: No, the code above does not change the size of the view, it only rotates it. Note that according to the documentation, a view that has a non-identity transform applied has an undefined value in the frame property.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try adding this in your info.plist:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Source: [ipad default-landscape not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856572/ipad-default-landscape-not-displaying)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

This will change orientation to potrait mode without rotating the  device.Likewise you can use for 
landscape also

Comment: This works, but it's not in the api docs, so you are probably breaking Apple's rules on private apis and could get your app rejected if you use it.